# How to filter out union data in large dataframe in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out inner data in my large data frame(1400,000 rows).
This is a very short and easy version of sample data:

```
a      b        c
35   0.1      234
1    0.1      554
2    0.2      654
23   0.4      2345
34   0.8      245
8    0.9      123
7    0.1      22
2    0.3      99
219  0.2      17
```

The result should look like `SQL query` as below:

```
select * from table where (a > 10 and a < 25) or b > 0.2 or c > 500
```

Is there a way of efficiently doing this in pandas/python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `query`:

```
df.query('(10<a<25) or (b>0.2) or (c>500)')
```

Or boolean indexing with:

```
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
    a    b     c
1   1  0.1   554
2   2  0.2   654
3  23  0.4  2345
4  34  0.8   245
5   8  0.9   123
7   2  0.3    99
```

Comment: Hi, if match this condition, can I add a new column, for example, if matches let `c` == 1, else let `c`==0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669368/how-to-add-a-new-column-if-match-where-mask-condition-in-python-pandas