# How to add a new column if match where/mask condition in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter out inner data in my large data frame(1400,000 rows).
This is a very short and easy version of sample data,

```
a      b        c       dt                   e
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       0
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
```

The result should look like `SQL query` as below:

```
select * from table where (a > 10 and a < 25) or b > 0.2 or c > 500
```

So I use `mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500) df[mask]`, can I add a new column to orignal data frame(140,0000 rows), for example, if match this df[mask] condition, let `c == 1`, else let `c==0`, I would like to keep original data but insert new column according condition.

Comment: `df['newcol'] = mask.astype(int)`.

Comment: @Psidom hey, How to add a new column without Length Value error if match where/mask condition after groupby in python/pandas?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680785/how-to-add-a-new-column-without-length-value-error-if-match-where-mask-condition